# How to reference a field from a multi tiered collection in Blueprism?

Tags: blueprism

I am using the Natural Language Google API in Blueprism. This API outputs a collection which contains sub collections. I want to reference a sub column from this collection. However, If I simply use the collection name.sub collection.sub collection.field I get an error. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the error you're getting? I've [re-created the collection by hand](https://i.imgur.com/MEg7EOJ.png) and [cannot reproduce any error](https://i.imgur.com/6crHuYp.png).

Comment: Added In now @esqew

Comment: From my anecdotal experience - this is a manifestation of known bug with the Evaluate Expression tool and nested/unset collections. If you run your process (as I have in my previously-linked example), the value will be pulled correctly. Consider filing an Enhancement Request in the Blue Prism portal.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was using the evaluate expression tool as I had never referenced a collection within a collection before and assumed I'd need some fine tuning. Thank you, feel free to post this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment above:

> From my anecdotal experience - this is a manifestation of known bug
>   with the Evaluate Expression tool and nested/unset Collections.
>
> If you run your process (as I have in my [[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTcPD.png)]),
>   the value will be pulled correctly. [You may want to consider] filing an Enhancement
>   Request in the Blue Prism portal.